# SciKit-learn transform for classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

it's the first time I'm approaching the scikit library. So I have this dataset which is already "cleaned" and is called dedups:

```
print(dedups)

 name  price vehicleType  \
1                                    A5_Sportback_2.7_Tdi  18300       coupe   
2                          Jeep_Grand_Cherokee_"Overland"   9800         suv   
3                                      GOLF_4_1_4__3TÜRER   1500  kleinwagen   
4                          Skoda_Fabia_1.4_TDI_PD_Classic   3600  kleinwagen   
5       BMW_316i___e36_Limousine___Bastlerfahrzeug__Ex...    650   limousine   
...                                                   ...    ...         ...   
371520                                       turbo_defekt   3200   limousine   
371524              Smart_smart_leistungssteigerung_100ps   1199      cabrio   
371525                 Volkswagen_Multivan_T4_TDI_7DC_UY2   9200         bus   
371526                             VW_Golf_Kombi_1_9l_TDI   3400       kombi   
371527       BMW_M135i_vollausgestattet_NP_52.720____Euro  28990   limousine   

        yearOfRegistration    gearbox  powerPS         model  kilometer  \
1                     2011    manuell      190  not-declared     125000   
2                     2004  automatik      163         grand     125000   
3                     2001    manuell       75          golf     150000   
4                     2008    manuell       69         fabia      90000   
5                     1995    manuell      102           3er     150000   
...                    ...        ...      ...           ...        ...   
371520                2004    manuell      225          leon     150000   
371524                2000  automatik      101        fortwo     125000   
371525                1996    manuell      102   transporter     150000   
371526                2002    manuell      100          golf     150000   
371527                2013    manuell      320       m_reihe      50000   

        monthOfRegistration fuelType       brand notRepairedDamage  namelen  
1                         5   diesel        audi                ja       20  
2                         8   diesel        jeep      not-declared       30  
3                         6   benzin  volkswagen              nein       18  
4                         7   diesel       skoda              nein       30  
5                        10   benzin         bmw                ja       50  
...                     ...      ...         ...               ...      ...  
371520                    5   benzin        seat                ja       12  
371524                    3   benzin       smart              nein       37  
371525                    3   diesel  volkswagen              nein       34  
371526                    6   diesel  volkswagen      not-declared       22  
371527                    8   benzin         bmw              nein       44  

[304133 rows x 13 columns]
```

So, first of all, my dependent variable is price. I then proceded by using `DataFrameMapper` in order to transform by dataset

```
labeled = DataFrameMapper([
    (['name', 'gearbox', 'notRepairedDamage', 'model', 'brand', 'fuelType', 'vehicleType'], 
      OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')), 
      ( ['yearOfRegistration','powerPS','kilometer','monthOfRegistration', 'namelen'], None)
                          ])

labeled_target = DataFrameMapper([
    (['price'], OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
    ])
```

```
labeled.fit(dedups)
labeled_target.fit(dedups)
```

So now i shall procede by creating my data for the train/test. And I'm doing like so:

```
X = labeled.transform(dedups.loc[:, dedups.columns != "price"])
Y = labeled_target.transform(dedups[['price']])
```

And here's the problem: if I run the code only for the Y everything is fine, but if I run also the X I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-6ec8ab95697a> in <module>
----> 1 X = labeled.transform(dedups.loc[:, dedups.columns != "price"])
      2 #Y = labeled_target.transform(dedups[['price']])
      3 print(Y)
      4 
      5 #matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 6.0)

~\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn_pandas\dataframe_mapper.py in transform(self, X)
    375         X       the data to transform
    376         """
--> 377         return self._transform(X)
    378 
    379     def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):

~\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn_pandas\dataframe_mapper.py in _transform(self, X, y, do_fit)
    343             # with sparse=True
    344             if not self.sparse:
--> 345                 stacked = stacked.toarray()
    346         else:
    347             stacked = np.hstack(extracted)

~\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py in toarray(self, order, out)
   1022         if out is None and order is None:
   1023             order = self._swap('cf')[0]
-> 1024         out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
   1025         if not (out.flags.c_contiguous or out.flags.f_contiguous):
   1026             raise ValueError('Output array must be C or F contiguous')

~\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in _process_toarray_args(self, order, out)
   1184             return out
   1185         else:
-> 1186             return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
   1187 
   1188 

MemoryError:
```

And I can't figure out the problem. Can you please help me?

Comment: `dedupes`/`X` is quite large.  I'm guessing that some of those categorical variables have a lot of levels in them as well.  So using `OneHotEncoder` will try to create a (potentially) huge dataframe, hence the `MemoryError`.  If that's the case, I suggest looking at alternative ways to encode the data.  E.g. group some levels, use `DictVectorizer` and/or `OrdinalEncoder` for some variables, etc.

Comment: Also, note that `OneHotEncoder` will encode numeric features (ie ints and floats)  if it receives them.

Comment: I see, so if I take a look at the price distribution and establish some price interval I can try with a fewer value that has to be encoded. I'm going to try it tomorrow. For the rest of the attributes is there a generale rule to e code a certain family of attributes or is just based on the good sense of the programmer?

Comment: And also, for this kind of problem is my approach correct or this task can be fulfilled in another, maybe better, way? Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to predict price you have a regression problem and don't need to encode `y`.  If you're trying to perform classification of some sort, then you do.  But the main issue is all of the features in `X`.  You don't need to encode interval/ratio variables, so start by separating out numeric and categorical features (look up `pandas`' `DataFrame.select_dtypes` method for that).  As for how best to encode, that depends on the data.  Is it nominal, ordinal, etc? How many levels?  Best to read up on encoding and then look at what data you have.

Comment: As you're using `sklearn` (albeit with `sklearn-pandas`) have a look at this example in the documentation for processing numeric and categorical features in a pipeline: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html.  It doesn't really address general approaches (as in, how to encode features with particular characteristics), but does have a lot of useful syntax for how to code a pipeline in python that deals with both categorical and numeric features.